# What does "STA" mean in "Broadcom STA driver"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been wondering for some time now, what does STA stand for?

Context: Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver
Example: http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

Answer (score 3):

STA seems to be short for Station in the broadcom sense.
I might however read it wrong.

The not that high reliable source but it was the best i could find with a small search:

Source:

[Openwrt](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/soc/soc.broadcom.bcm47xx)

Qoute: b43

This is the open source driver built by the community based on reverse engineered specifications of the proprietary Broadcom driver. This is the driver that is included in the current OpenWrt builds. It is also in the mainline Linux kernel. This driver supports most of the current available Broadcom WiFi cores. It has support for station (STA), AP, AdHoc, Mesh and other modes, but it just supports 802.11g rates and does not support 802.11g operating in the 5GHz band.

Answer (score -1):

From the context of the package I would say it means "static". This is a hybrid binary driver which is agnostic to the specific versions and distributions. Static linking most of the time makes binaries easier to distribute to different user environments (at the cost of program being larger). This would suggest, that STA is a short-hand "static".

More info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking
- http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt

Comment: i am not quite sure why this answer is downvoted, without an broadcom engineer actually having told somewhere its hard to actually know if its either static, Station or maybe something else.

Comment: It was downvoted because it's wrong. In this context, [STA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station_(networking)) means station.